# Unable to install updates after installing python pyenv

Tags: 16.04, updates

I am new to Ubuntu. Sometime back I installed Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 and after installing pyenv my terminal was changed from

```
waheed@waheed-Lenovo-Z51-70:~$
```

to

```
(general) waheed@waheed-Lenovo-Z51-70:~$
```

After this I am not able to install updates or any other software.
It gives me the following error:

```
(general) waheed@waheed-Lenovo-Z51-70:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for waheed: 
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial InRelease [18.1 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [4,404 B]
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages [4,408 B]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages [306 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]  
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages [289 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [581 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en [130 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [59.2 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [49.6 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages [145 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages [129 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.6 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [56.1 kB]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [561 kB]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [235 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [304 kB]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [203 kB]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [7,804 B]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages [7,804 B]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [506 kB]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [490 kB]
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en [197 kB]
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [163 kB]
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [205 kB]
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [14.9 kB]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14.0 kB]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,888 B]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,324 B]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,672 B]
Fetched 5,041 kB in 18s (278 kB/s)                                             
Reading package lists... Done
(general) waheed@waheed-Lenovo-Z51-70:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
(general) waheed@waheed-Lenovo-Z51-70:~$
```

I even tried `apt-get -f install` but no luck.
Please help me to fix it.

Comment: How did you install `pyenv`? Is that the entirety of the error message? If not, please include everything you see.

Comment: (general) waheed@waheed-Lenovo-Z51-70:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for waheed: 
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/python-3.6/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]

Comment: Fetched 306 kB in 7s (42.6 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
(general) waheed@waheed-Lenovo-Z51-70:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
(general) waheed@waheed-Lenovo-Z51-70:~$

Comment: Include this information in your question itself, not as comments, so that it is easier to read. Thanks.

Comment: About how dis install pyenv, I followed instructions from askubuntu.com (unfortunately I couldn't find the same page now). And that is my guess that that is causing the problem, because before it the updates were installing normally.